# Can not load component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I get an error when page is loaded:

> ```
> compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Type LoginComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: LoginModule and AppModule! Please
> ```
>
> consider moving LoginComponent to a higher module that imports
>   LoginModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that
>   exports and includes LoginComponent then import that NgModule in
>   LoginModule and AppModule.

In `@NgModule` I have the following declaration:

```
declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, LanguageComponent]
```

How to fix this?

In the top of file app.module I have import:

```
import { LanguageComponent } from './language/language.component';
import  { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
```

Below in section:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    HomeModule,
    AboutModule,
    LoginModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule,
    LocalStorageModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ReCaptchaModule,
    TextMaskModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCheckboxModule
  ],

  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, LanguageComponent],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    HiderPipe,
    TimerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: some more code will definitely help

Comment: Components need to also be in the `exports` of a ngModule.

Comment: Where is exports? Can you show

Comment: They do not, only if you need to export them..

Comment: paste code of your language.component.ts

Comment: and paste entire NgModule

Comment: Added full error message.

Comment: Which module is this?

Comment: Seems straightforward, remove LoginComponent from the declarations in AppModule as it is already part of the LoginModule.

Comment: It clearly states that `LoginComponent` is declared in 2 modules. I assume that the component will only be used in the `LoginModule` so it doesn't make sense declaring it in the `AppModule`. Remove it from there.

Comment: From this pack: https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit

Comment: AppModule is empty: `export class AppModule { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a **Component** to another module you have to do the following things. Let's assume Login component is in **LoginModule** , In order to use this component outside of the module declare and export the component. If you are not export the component, you couldn't use component outside of the UserModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule,BrowserModule,FormsModule],
  declarations:[LoginComponent],
  exports: [LoginComponent],
})
export class LoginModule {

 }
```

and then you no need to again declare the **LoginComponent** in to the App module. Just Import the LoginModule where **LoginComponent** resides.

```
 @NgModule({
      imports:[RouterModule,BrowserModule,FormsModule,LoginModule],
      declarations:[],
      exports: [],
    })
    export class AppModule {

     }
```

Comment: I said the same, and his response was "I added here, without them is not working too" :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Doubled import of loginModuel.
    you have to remove loginModuel in imports: []